# How to select values by date field (not as simple as it sounds)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `tblMK` The table contains a date time field. 
What I wish to do is create a query which will each time, `select the 2 latest entries (by the datetime column)` and then get the date difference between them and show only that.

How would I go around creating this expression. This doesn't necessarily need to be a query, it could be a view/function/procedure or what ever works. I have created a function called `getdatediff` which receives to dates, and returns a string the says (x days y hours z minutes) basically that will be the calculated field. So how would I go around doing this?

**Edit**: I need to each time select 2 and 2 and so on until the oldest one. There will always be an even amount of rows.

Comment: The date difference betwenn the latest 2 dates or between each pair of dates for the whole table?

Comment: @Mihai sounds like the latter.

Comment: Please add a data sample and the expected result to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use only sql like this:

```
create table t1(c1 integer, dt datetime);

insert into t1 values
(1, getdate()),
(2, dateadd(day,1,getdate())),
(3, dateadd(day,2,getdate()));

with temp as (select top 2 dt 
  from t1
  order by dt desc)
select datediff(day,min(dt),max(dt)) as diff_of_dates
from temp;
```

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/327a5/5)

Comment: I can't create a new table this needs to be done within a view/query

Comment: Can you show your table or view ddl. Without any further information I can only give you some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL use limit clause

```
select max(a.updated_at)-min(a.updated_at)
From
( select * from mytable order by updated_at desc limit 2 ) a
```

Comment: Why suggest a MySQL solution on a question about SQL Server?

Comment: My mistake only saw SQL tag and didn't see that SQLServer tag initially

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I found the solution please ignore the additional columns they are for my db:

```
; with numbered as (
Select part,taarich,hulia,mesirakabala,
rowno = row_number() OVER (Partition by parit    order.by taarich)
From tblMK)
Select a.rowno-1,a.part,  a.Julia,b.taarich,as.taarich_kabala,a.taarich,  a.mesirakabala,getdatediff(b.taarich,a.taarich) as due
From numbered a
Left join numbered b ON b.parit=a.parit
And b.rowno = a.rowno - 1
Where b.taarich is not null
Order by part,taarich
```

Sorry about mistakes I might of made, I'm on my smartphone.